# Magento require js error

Tags: magento2

Currently, some Magento js returned 404 error. Please check attached screenshot for the same.[image]

Comment: try to redeploy your static content and give permission and clear pub/static folder

Answer (score 1):

You should try this all M2 command:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Magento/backend
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
```

This will solved your issue.

Comment: If this helps you. Please mark as a right answer.